# Why are there no animals in "The Matrix"?

Tags: the-matrix, animals

Aside from the repetitive appearance of the black cat, I can't remember seeing any living animals, either inside the Matrix simulation or in Zion.

How come? Is there an in-universe explanation?

[image]

Comment: Don't forget the crows that fly in front of Smith in *Reloaded*.  In Zion it's no doubt because of massive die-offs from the war, in the Matrix we probably just never encountered any because they weren't relevant to the story.

Comment: Can't get them to wear skintight leather suits and shades easily.

Comment: Just before the Smith scene, the Oracle explains that there's a program controlling the behavior of birds. It makes sense to think that cats and other animals are computer generated.

Comment: Most of the scenes take place in densely populated urban areas, which aren't exactly known for their large numbers of bear, elk, or bison. We do see small pets and birds, both of which are common in urban environments. I wouldn't expect to see anything much larger than a dog in most cities.

Comment: Unless an animal is important to the story, movie makers are going to try very hard to leave it out. "Animal actors" are often expensive and frustrating, more so as more specific actions are required of them. Remember, we also don't see anything but city in the Matrix; that doesn't mean there is no "countryside", just that it wasn't relevant to this story.

Comment: Erm.. the famous black cat Déjà vu scene?

Comment: Don't forget the cow that made an appearance on Cypher's plate in his meeting with A. Smith

Comment: @SaturnsEye: Erm.. read the first eight words of the question?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ha, my bad, quickly view at work so I skimmed over it

Comment: Same reason there is no spoon... or that everything tastes like chicken.

Comment: There are pigeons.

Comment: @22ndCenturyFza - Are you referring to the pigeons in the "girl in the red dress" training simulation? Because those aren't in the Matrix or in Zion...

Comment: @hitchhiker - Is there anything else you were hoping to see in an answer before you give it an acceptance?

Comment: @Oldcat https://theycallmejane.files.wordpress.com/2010/12/draft_lens9869081module121632391photo_1_1285340016joe-cool-wallpaper.jpg

Comment: Because once the machine had got done coding read Skyrim and read dead redemption 1 and 2 it realised that creating realistic animal AI is hard :).

Answer (score 133, accepted):

Although we do see animals inside the Matrix on numerous occasions (see below), the [word of god answer](http://web.archive.org/web/20060315041403/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/larryandychat_index.html) is that all of these animals are simulated:

> **TheTrinityACMXCL:** *What about the animals in the Matrix? Are they real animals or just computer-generated images?*
>
> **Wachowski Bros:** *Sadly, they are all computer generated images.*

This was backed up by Phil Osterhoose (Assistant to the
Wachowskis) in [*The Art of the Matrix*](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Art-Matrix-Larry-Wachowski/dp/1840231734)

> *A lot of people have asked if the animals in the Matrix are also
> hooked up in pods. Unfortunately, they are not. They're all computer-generated images.*

---

### Matrix Films

In addition to the "*Woah, deja-vu!*" cat seen in the first Matrix film we also see a large number of crows in *The Matrix Reloaded*.

[image]

As well as a dozen or so live fish.

[image]

and a flock of birds in *The Matrix Resurrections*

[image]

### Animatrix

*[Kid's Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368574/)* features some more crows and an (unnamed) cat.

[image]
[image]

There's a dog in *[World Record](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/World_Record)*.

[image]

There are also doves seen in the Animatrix story *[Beyond](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Beyond)* as well as another dog, some butterflies, a considerable number of rats and two cats; Yuki and another unnamed.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

*[A Detective Story](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0366177/)* contains another cat (named Dinah).

[image]

The *Animatrix* story *[Matriculated](http://matrix.wikia.com/wiki/Matriculated)* contains what appears to be a cybernetically enhanced monkey named Baby. This is especially noteworthy because the story takes place *outside* the Matrix, providing evidence of the survival of higher mammals.

[image]

### Matrix Comics

In the Matrix comic *[Broadcast Depth](http://web.archive.org/web/20040603010807/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/sien01.html)*, one of the characters encounters an octopus eating a crab as well as a large school of fish.

[image]
[image]

The central character of the Matrix comic *[Butterfly](http://web.archive.org/web/20040607022725/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/daveg1a.html)* is arguably the titular butterfly.

[image]

*[Deja Vu](http://web.archive.org/web/20040607184739/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/paul_1.html)* mentions an (unseen by us) infestation of ladybugs and we also see an American robin.

[image]

*[Let It All Fall Down](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034339/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/paul_fallmain.html)* features a woodland scene sporting an eagle.

[image]

*[Run, Saga, Run](http://web.archive.org/web/20040603211459/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/kpage00_755.html)* features a white rat.

[image]

*[Sweating the Small Stuff](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614050701/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/bills_1.html)* includes a cat and a spider.

[image]

*[The Miller's Tale](http://web.archive.org/web/20040614034230/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/paulcMiller1a.html)* is again notable because we see wildlife surviving **outside** of the Matrix. This includes small mammals, ducks, frogs, insects, arachnids and slugs.

[image]

and from *[A Sword of a Different Color](http://web.archive.org/web/20040607143211/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/rl_cmp/troy01.html)*, we see someone eating what appears to be uncooked rat.

[image]

---

The original concept art by Geoff Darrow contains a hungry mouse.

[image]

And of course, who could forget that Cypher is eating what appears to be a large chunk of dead cow?

[image]

Comment: I think he's eating oatmel. How would he know the difference?

Comment: Crows are smart, but i don't think they're worth the effort of using real crow power, and thus are simulations akin to the horses in "Program" of [The Animatrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Animatrix).

Comment: @ceesTimmerman - I deliberately excluded a whole bunch of animals only seen in "the construct" including horses, doves, deer and various insects and rodents.

Comment: +1 for bringing The Animatrix into the discussion. It frequently gets missed out when answering relevant questions yet contains a large chunk of back story.

Comment: @ianlewis - And according to the Wachowski's is a fully canon extension of the films.

Comment: @Richard And mightily entertaining too!

Comment: @DVK Oatmeal is PEOPLE!

Comment: @Richard, where did you take the "Aquarium"-Scene with fish from? I can not remember where that was.

Comment: @hitchhiker - Matrix Reloaded - 41:06. Neo on the street. The fish are on the right-hand side of the screen./

Comment: @Richard Right. Easy to oversee at first, but there they are... Thanks!

Comment: @hitchhiker -If you spot any more, don't hesitate to edit them in...

Comment: @DVK - It might interest you to know that in the original script, the white oatmeal contained meaty chunks of what would later turn out to be cockroach.