# Are animals in the matrix real or programs?

Tags: the-matrix

There are animals in the matrix. Does this mean that real animals are hooked up to the machine and give it energy and exist in the matrix? Or every time there is an animal seen in the matrix, it's just a program?

I don't think this question is a duplicate of "why there is no animals in the matrix?". Why are there only programmed animals in the Matrix? Why wouldn't they use animals as a source of energy as they use humans?

Comment: @WadCheber no no, this is the opposite. Why is there no animals in the real world?

Comment: That question is answered in the one I linked.

Comment: TheTrinityACMXCL: What about the animals in the Matrix? Are they real animals or just computer-generated images?

Wachowski Bros: Sadly, they are all computer generated images.
This was backed up by Phil Osterhoose (Assistant to the Wachowskis) in The Art of the Matrix

A lot of people have asked if the animals in the Matrix are also hooked up in pods. Unfortunately, they are not. They're all computer-generated images."
Phil Osterhoose (Assistant to the Wachowski Brothers) - The Art of the Matrix

Comment: Same exact quotes.

Comment: @wadcheber - Identical, even down to the formatting changes I made

Answer (score 5):

They are not real according to the [Wachowski's](http://web.archive.org/web/20060315041403/http://whatisthematrix.warnerbros.com/cmp/larryandychat_index.html)

> **TheTrinityACMXCL:** What about the animals in the Matrix? Are they real animals or just computer-generated images?
>
> **Wachowski's**: Sadly, they are all computer generated images.

And also according to [The Art of The Matrix](http://www.amazon.co.uk/The-Art-Matrix-Larry-Wachowski/dp/1840231734)

> **Phil Osterhoose:** A lot of people have asked if the animals in the Matrix are also hooked up in pods. Unfortunately, they are not. They're all computer-generated images."

This is all contained in the answer [provided by Richard here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/71564/in-the-matrix-why-are-there-no-animals)

I was going to put some stuff about the cat and Deja Vu but it would be superfluous to an answer that already answers your question.

Comment: It is traditional to credit the author of an answer if you plan to use bits of their work in your own answer. ..

Comment: @Richard Sorry, I flagged this question as a duplicate and thought id removed this as an answer hence not crediting you as whilst writing it down I just thought this is the same question and is answered so stopped writing it. Very sorry. Would you like me to delete this as I thought I had done or link this to your own answer?

Comment: I leave that to you. As long as it's credited, I'm more than happy for you to keep the upvotes :-)

Comment: @Richard hopefully that has done it? I will learn not to try to delete from my phone in future as it didn't seem to accept it. Really didn't mean to cause any offence.